# What is this effect called? Is it film-grain?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, inkscape, photoshop-effects

What is this effect called? Is it film-grain? It kind of looks like but the grains are bigger. Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: photoshop: Filter > Noise > Add Noise

Comment: http://www.tutorialsbucket.com/noise-texture-background-effect-in-adobe-photoshop-cs5

Answer (score 3):

This looks very much like monochrome Gaussian (as opposed to Uniform, which it's not) noise at a low opacity. If I were going to reproduce the effect, I'd do this:

- Add the noise to a white layer in Multiply or Darken mode @ about 20% opacity above the object. (The example below is in Darken mode at 21%.)
- Use Photoshop's `Blend If` function (in the Blending Options dialog) to allow the whitest parts of the underlying object to show through.

[image]

- Scale up the noise layer. Scaling it up makes noise "grain" edges less sharp and gives that "blobby" look.

[image]

Comment: Glad to help. It was an interesting exercise, actually. :)

Answer (score 2):

Film grain is a possible answer.

Another is *noise*:

[image: noise screenshot]

You might also try to look up *dithering* - it's usually associated with GIF compression but can be used in an artsy way.